# How granular should data in memcached be?

Tags: caching, performance, memcached

Something I'm curious about.. What would be "most efficient" to cache the generation of, say, an RSS feed? Or an API response (like the response to `/api/films/info/a12345`).

For example, should I cache the entire feed, and try and return that, as psuedo code:

```
id = GET_PARAMS['id']
cached = memcache.get("feed_%s" % id)
if cached is not None:
    return cached
else:
    feed = generate_feed(id)
    memcache.put("feed_%s" % id, feed)
    return feed
```

Or cache the queries result, and generate the document each time?

```
id = sanitise(GET_PARMS['id'])
query = query("SELECT title, body FROM posts WHERE id=%%", id)

cached_query_result = memcache.get(query.hash())
if cached_query_result:
    feed = generate_feed(cached_query_result)
    return feed
else:
    query_result = query.execute()
    memcache.put("feed_%s" % id, query_result)
    feed = generate_feed(query_result)
```

(Or, some other way I'm missing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for my experience, You should use multiple levels of cache. Implement *both* of Your solutions (provided that it's not the only code that uses `"SELECT title, body FROM posts WHERE id=%%"`. If it is use only the first one).

In the second version of code, You `memcache.get(query.hash())`, but `memcache.put("feed_%s" % id, query_result)`. This might not work as You want it to (unless You have an unusual version of hash() ;) ).

I would avoid `query.hash()`. It's better to use something like posts-title-body-%id. Try deleting a video when it's stored in cache as `query.hash()`. It can hang there for months as a zombie-video.

By the way:

```
id = GET_PARMS['id']
query = query("SELECT title, body FROM posts WHERE id=%%", id)
```

You take something from GET and put it right into the sql query? That's bad (will result in SQL injection attacks).

Comment: "Implement both" is a good point.. The code was Python-looking pseudo-code (which I made up for the question. If the code were real, obviously id would be validated and the query() function would properly escape the parameter)

Comment: Still, posting this might confuse newbies. Always better to add a sanitize(GET_PARAMS['id']) or something. Good question, btw.

Comment: I've been working in many very high traffic sites with APIs and all that stuff; and I totally agree with this answer. My products have always implemented both caching; the result of the SELECT ; and each individual item as well.

The main reason being that /request?id=123 might use the same "small blocks" than /request?id=123&order=date-desc ; but in different order. By You can then reuse cached results more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the usage pattern, but all things equal I'd vote for the first way because you'll only do the work of generating the feed 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your app does...  The only way to answer this is to get some performance numbers from your existing app.  Then you can find the code that takes the largest amount of time and work on improving that one.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested here I'd profile your code and work out what is the slowest or most expensive part of the operation.